# VS 2008 find/replace with collapsed regions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I just started using `#region` / `#endregion` to organize my C# code.  Now it seems that <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> (quick find & replace) with `LookIn=CurrentDocument` does NOT replace within any #regions of code that happen to be collapsed at the moment.

1. Am I dreaming or is this really the behavior of VS 2008 ?  (Seems dangerous to have global replace depend on your active window state.)
2. if I'm not dreaming is there an edit setting buried somewhere to change the behavior ?

Comment: Yep there's an option for that...

Comment: thanks for the lightning fast answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Check the "Search Hidden Text" option of the Find and Replace dialog.](http://arcware.net/find-and-replace-problem-in-visual-studio-nevermind/)